# OPAL-Framework: Get thrown exceptions of a method

Tags: scala, static-analysis, opal-framework

In the OPAL-Framework, is how can I get all thrown exceptions from a method or its descriptor? I could not find any method returning them.

I am only interested in those exceptions, which are listed in the throws-declaration of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Method` object provides the method `exceptionTable` which return an Option of the type `ExceptionTable`. If the table is not empty, it contains the list of declared exceptions.